# How to prevent carrierwave from adding the filename string to the mounted column when file is not uploaded?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, carrierwave

I am using Rails and ActiveRecord.
I have carrierwave mounted on one of the columns(`:logo`) of a model(`Listing`). My default filename is `"disp_logo"`. Let's say I just do `Listing.create!` In this case, I haven't really uploaded any file. I did not do `Listing.logo=<some file>` or `Listing.remote_logo_url=<some url>`. But, carrierwave still inserts the string `"disp_logo"` in the `:logo` column. Why does it do that? How can I prevent carrierwave from doing so?

My uploader class has the following methods:

```
def store_dir
  "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
end

def filename
  "disp_logo"
end
```

That's what I mean by default filename.
I want the column `:logo` to have `NULL` if image is not uploaded. Instead it has `"disp_logo"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with a solution that fits my use-case better.

```
class LogoUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  attr_accessor :upload_failed

  def filename
    upload_failed ? "failed" : "disp_logo"
  end
end

class SomeModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  mount_uploader :logo, LogoUploader

  def some_method_that_assigns_a_file_and_uploads_it
    self.remote_logo_url = <some_url>
                  OR
    self.logo = <some file>
    <some_other_logic>
    save!
  rescue
    logo.upload_failed = true
    save!
  end
end
```

This way, I know which records were processed`:logo #=> "disp_logo"`, which records failed`:logo #=> "failed"` and which are yet to be processed`:logo #=> nil`

Answer (score 1):

It would seem you created your migration with "disp_logo" as the default value for your column. You should set the default image in your uploader instead, like this:

```
  # Provide a default URL as a default if there hasn't been a file uploaded:
  def default_url
    "/" + [version_name, "disp_logo.jpg"].compact.join('_')
  end
```

Or if you use rails 3.1 and the assets pipeline:

```
  # Include the Sprokets helpers for Rails 3.1+ asset pipeline compatibility:
  include Sprockets::Helpers::RailsHelper
  include Sprockets::Helpers::IsolatedHelper

  # Provide a default URL as a default if there hasn't been a file uploaded:
  def default_url
    asset_path [version_name, "disp_logo.jpg"].compact.join('_')
  end
```

**Edit:**

Modify your `filename` method as follows:

```
  def filename
    "something.jpg" unless original_filename.nil?
  end
```

Comment: Thanks! But that's not exactly what I meant. I have edited my question.